# RIAK and Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, riak

I am learning about RIAK and thinking about using it to store JSON objects.
I have also used swagger UI many times in the past to document API's.

I would like to build a simple example bucket in RIAK with a swagger UI style API. This could be simple out of the box functionality. All I need to do is define a model for the JSON object and it should be possibly to automatically create a swagger file with get, post, put options for that object.

I have googled "swagger Riak" but I can't find any articles with both words in them.

Is there a better phrase I should be searching for?

Comment: I can't say that I completely understand your question. Riak is a database. It does expose an HTTP API, but you have to describe it using a Swagger scheme, and then to run the generated Swagger app somehow. Is this what you're trying to do? If you're looking for a simple Web app for browsing date stored in Riak, have a look at https://github.com/basho-labs/riak_explorer and https://github.com/basho-labs/rekon (old and limited). Also https://docs.basho.com/community/projects/ can be a good place to check out.

Comment: I am investigating using it as a web datamart. It would be nice to define a customer object structure as use riak to store it automatically giving me a rest API for the customer without any middle layer at all. I was thinking of some way of autogenerating swagger files but I thought it must have already been done.